# ios11 Safari Web App, overlapping title bar

Tags: webview, safari, ios11

With ios11, when a site is added to home screen which has the web-app enabled. The title bar overlaps the site content in certain cases. 
To reproduce the issue -

1. Add any site which has web-app enabled to home screen
2. Open the added app from the home screen Change the orientation from portrait to landscape
3. Now from landscape to portrait again

Now you will notice that the title bar overlapping the site content.
I have raised an issue at bug reporter with apple but did not get any response
The meta tag for the title bar is default, which behaves properly until the above steps are done

This is happening with all the sites which have the ability to be added to the home screen and function as an app. Any suggested fixes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved in ios 11.3 beta version. Hopefully this stays when the actual release version is out.